# Cypress web sockets error: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing

Tags: vue.js, testing, websocket, cypress

I am trying to test a VueJs application with Cypress.

Everything works well except the websocket connection that fails with the message:

`Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing`

On dev or deployed, it works without issue and the 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is present but no clue why it fails with Cypress.

Any idea?